# How to delete an old version of mongodb and install the new one in cloud9 IDE?

Tags: mongodb, cloud9-ide

I'm using the cloud9 IDE and I'm trying to connect through the mongo shell to a mongodb instance running on mongolab.  Mongolab now runs mongodb version 3.0 but cloud9 has version 2.6 installed.

I've tried following the instructions on the mongodb website for installing on ubuntu 14.04 using the mongodb binaries, and although all of the commands it instructed me to use were executed without errors, I didn't understand exactly what was happening, and when I checked the mongodb version with `mongod --version` it still said I was running the old version - 2.6.10

Can someone explain the steps to uninstall the old version and install the new version of mongodb in cloud9?

Comment: Reda this turorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/ for insatllation and uninstall

Comment: To connect to mongoLAB read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-setup-mongodb-in-mongolab/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to remove the existing mongodb:

`sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge`

Then we can follow instructions from [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb).

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10`
2. `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

I hope this helps.