# Connecting Cloud9 and MongoLab -- Driver Versions?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, cloud9-ide, database

I am having issues connecting to MongoLab from my Cloud9 interface:

```
esend7881:~/workspace (master) $ mongo ds01235.mongolab.com:12345/mydb(http://ds01235.mongolab.com:12345/mydb) -u root -p root
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: ds01235.mongolab.com:12345/mydb(http://ds01235.mongolab.com:12345/mydb)
2015-10-27T17:58:43.597+0000 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1292
exception: login failed
```

I noticed that cloud9 uses Mongo 2.6.11.

I tried upgrading this to a version that is >3 using `apt-get upgrade/update/install/etc` and nothing works. I'm not sure if maybe Mongo 2.6.11 is the Mongo 3 driver (if so, version numbers are very confusing here)

So, if mongo versions are not the issue here, any idea what is?

I emailed Mongolab support and they pointed me in the direction of Cloud9, and it seems like StackOverflow is the place to get Cloud9 Support.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204739/how-to-delete-an-old-version-of-mongodb-and-install-the-new-one-in-cloud9-ide

Comment: Bingo, thanks. Guess that answers this question